# Dealing with NaNs in scipy.stats.chisquare

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan, chi-squared

I'm trying to perform a chi^2 test on some data which contains NaNs. Here's a MWE:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare as chi2
import numpy as np
x = [16, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12]
chi2(x)
```

outputs

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=2.0, pvalue=0.8491450360846096)
```

but

```
x[-1] = np.nan
chi2(x)
```

gives

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)
```

Applying a mask with

```
mask = ~np.isnan(x)
chi2(x[mask])
```

results in

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3c009fd66f63> in <module>
----> 1 chi2(x[mask])

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I think (hope) the NaNs in my actual data are what's causing the issue. Does `scipy.stats.chisquare` have an in-built way of dealing with NaNs, like, for example, `spearmanr` does with its `nan_policy`? If not, what's the best way of dealing with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is a list; a boolean array (for that matter, any array) cannot be used to index a list.

```
In [244]: x = [16, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12]                                          
In [245]: x[-1] = np.nan                                                        
In [246]: mask = ~np.isnan(x)                                                   
In [247]: x[mask]                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-fee3ce9a3be1> in <module>
----> 1 x[mask]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
In [248]: mask                                                                  
Out[248]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

That error occurred before `chi2` was called.

Now if `x` were a `ndarray` it just might work :)

```
In [249]: x = np.array([16, 18, 16, 14, 12, 12])                                
In [250]: x[mask]                                                               
Out[250]: array([16, 18, 16, 14, 12])
```